# Javascript regex for dates

Tags: javascript, regex

Could somebody write a JavaScript compatible RegExp to match the below formats of dates?

ex.

- 11.09.
- 11.9
- 11.9.
- 11.9.2014
- 11.9.14

I tried

```
var regex=new RegExp("([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1})[.](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[.][0-9]{4})");
```

but don't know how to update it to capture everything listed above. It only works for `11.09.2014`.

Comment: Yes many of us can write but did you also attempt to write it?

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You can try with that http://regexpal.com

Comment: You want to read about the [`?` optional operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])[.](0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:[.](?:\d{2}|\d{4})?)?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV6iJ3/2)

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I just tried it for `22.9.13` and it doesn't work. I think perhaps you meant to use **`(0?1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`** for the day range

Comment: Yes indeed it should be `(0?1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`. Thanks for pointing it out, I edited it now.